# ¿Cómo matar (kill) una conexión en SQL Server desde un query?

Tags: sql-server, session, kill

Estoy intentando eliminar una conexión a una base de datos, combinando el comando `kill` con un `query` que consulta el `session_id` desde la tabla `dm_exec_sessions` filtrando por el nombre de mi base de datos. Según la [documentación de Microsoft](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/kill-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) el comando `kill` tiene la siguiente sintaxis:

```
KILL session_id;
```

Este es lo que he intentado:

```
kill select s.session_id FROM sys.dm_exec_sessions AS s where s.database_id 
in (select db.database_id from sys.databases db where db.name like 'dbname');
```

Pero me aparece el siguiente error:

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 1 Incorrect syntax near the keyword
>   'select'.

Agradezco su ayuda, saludos!

Answer (score 2):

Al margen del problema de la sintaxis, lo que estas haciendo es intentar eliminar todas las sesiones existentes y eso puede acarrear problemas.

Deberías buscar el `session_id` que te interese y hacer un `kill @session_id` pues `kill`espera un valor escalar entero (`int`).

Si necesitas eliminar más de un proceso, deberás hacerlo con un cursor que elimine uno a uno cada `session_id`.

Comment: Entiendo tu respuesta y te agradezco, saludos!

Answer (score 1):

Si quieres matar una sesión debes hacer tal y como explicó Roger, pero si quieres matar todas las conexiones a una base de datos en particular deberías ejecutar una consulta y armar las sentencias para cada proceso.

```
Declare @StrSQL Varchar(Max)

Select @StrSQL = STRING_AGG( 'kill ' + Cast(sp.spid As Varchar), Char(13) + Char(10) )
From sysprocesses As sp
    Inner Join sys.databases As sd
       On sd.database_id = dbid
Where sd.name = 'NombreDB'
    And sp.spid <> @@SpId
    And sp.kpid = 0

Exec (@StrSQL)
```